# Caused By: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "name"

Tags: postgresql

am trying to load data from Pgadmin4 table named `event` and `event type`. Mapping of name column of eventtype table to oracle target table (stg), throws an error Caused By:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "name".`

Could anyone help me on these? How can we solve this?
Source: pgadmin4
target: oracle

Comment: How are you loading the data? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [edit] your question and show us the query. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)